# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SelectedCategoriesIds'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I got that Error

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'SelectedCategoriesIds'.

My Model code:

```
   public class NewsViewModel
    {
        public int NewsId { get; set; }
        public string NewsTitle { get; set; }
        public string NewsBody { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime NewsDate { get; set; }
        public string NewsImagePath { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase NewsImageFile { get; set; }
        public int[] SelectedCategoriesIds { get; set; }

    }
```

My code in Controller:

```
var list = db.Categories.ToList();
ViewBag.CategoryList = from c in list 
                       orderby c.CategoryName 
                       select new SelectListItem 
                                 { 
                                   Value = c.CategoryId.ToString(), 
                                   Text = c.CategoryName.Trim() 
                                 };
```

and in Razor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCategoriesIds,
                     (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CategoryList,
                        new 
                        { 
                          id = "dropdownOne", 
                          @class = "form-control", 
                          multiple = "true" 
                         }
                      )
```

Comment: show your model class

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i edited the code , Thank you so much

Comment: ``SelectedCategoriesIds `` should be ``int`` not ``int[]``

Comment: if int not int[] how i can loop through it? i need an array of Ids

Comment: dropdownlist returns single value which is selected

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, ah, i see but what if i want to return multiple values? should i use MultiSelectList ? if yes please show me how i can use MultiSelectList in my code .thank you so much

Comment: @EhsanSajjad .. what do you think?

Comment: See the answers posted, you need to use chexkboxlist or listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DropDownListFor only supports one selection. It looks like you need a CheckBoxListFor since it's a multiple choices.

You can check my little nuget package CheckBoxList.Mvc which provides you CheckBoxListFor

https://github.com/stephenzeng/CheckBoxList.Mvc

At the moment it does not support int[] but I am going to add it now.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple Select you can use

- @Html.ListBoxFor(x=>x.model.SelectedCategoriesIds, (IEnumerable)ViewBag.CategoryList, new { id = "AnyName", Multiple = "multiple"})

Comment: thank you for your help but still the same error